# Reading a specific XML node within several of the same type

Tags: xml, parsing, powershell

I am parsing a config tasks and I need to get all the tasks that don't have an "email on failure" part. Below is the section from the xml of the tasks.

```
<Settings>
    <Tasks>
        <Task ID="916360623" Name="name1" Active="0" NextEID="21" CacheNames="random">
            <Schedules/>
            <NextActions>
                <NextAction DoIfSuccess="1" DoIfFailure="0" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Task" TaskID="545310265"/>
                <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="385322183" AddressTo="email1@email.com, email2@email.com" Subject="[TaskName] - [TaskStatus]" Message="emailMessageFail"/>
                <NextAction DoIfSuccess="1" DoIfFailure="0" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="385322183" AddressTo="email1@email.com, email2@email.com" Subject="[TaskName] - [TaskStatus]" Message="emailMessageSuccess"/>
            </NextActions>
        </Task>
        <Task ID="701754236" Name="Task2" Active="0" NextEID="21" CacheNames="random">
            <NextActions>
                <NextAction DoIfSuccess="1" DoIfFailure="0" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Task" TaskID="840519929"/>
                <NextAction DoIfSuccess="0" DoIfFailure="1" DoIfNoAction="0" DoAfter="Task" Type="Email" HostID="385322183" AddressTo="email1@email.com, email2@email.com" Subject="[TaskName] - [TaskStatus]" Message="emailMessage"/>
            </NextActions>
        </Task>             
    </Tasks>
</Settings>
```

I have a powershell script that cycles through each task, and each `<NextAction>` however, it doesn't seem to successfully only take the tasks I want. What would be the best way to get a report of the tasks that dont have a `DoIfFailue="1"` AND `Type="Email"`?

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted
[xml]$config = Get-Content c:\path\config.xml
$allTasks = @()
foreach($task in $config.Settings.Tasks.task){
    $taskID = $task.name
    foreach($nextAction in $task.NextActions.NextAction){
        if(($nextAction.DoIfFailure = "1") -AND ($nextAction.type = "Email")){
            $address = $nextAction.addressto
            $subject = $nextAction.subject
            $message = $nextAction.message
            $allTasks += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'ID' = $taskID; 'emailAddress' = $address; 'emailSubject' = $subject; 'emailMessage' = $message})
        }
    }
}
$allTasks | Export-Csv -Path c:\path\output.csv -notype
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equals test in Powershell is `-eq`, not `=`. So this:

```
if(($nextAction.DoIfFailure = "1") -AND ($nextAction.type = "Email")){
```

should be this:

```
if(($nextAction.DoIfFailure -eq "1") -AND ($nextAction.type -eq "Email")){
```

Also, you don't need `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` every time, just run once per server.

Comment: ah darn it. It's been a while since i've down ps work. That would be it. Thanks!

Comment: has an equal test ever been `=` at all ?  I thought they always were `==` :-)

Comment: @Graimer: Sure, try VB (or VB.NET).

Comment: ahh, thanks. haven't done any VB since I'm not a programmer. I've only tried python, PS, c# and java.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this:

```
$allTasks = @()
$doc=New-Object -typename System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load("c:\path\config.xml")
$nextActions = $doc.SelectNodes("//NextAction[@DoIfFailure='1' and @Type='Email']")

foreach($nextAction in $nextActions ){
            $address = $nextAction.addressto
            $subject = $nextAction.subject
            $message = $nextAction.message
            $allTasks += @(New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{'ID' = $taskID; 'emailAddress' = $address; 'emailSubject' = $subject; 'emailMessage' = $message})
    }

$allTasks | Export-Csv -Path c:\path\output.csv -notype
```